# Parse Int returning NaN despite number in text

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I have been working with a transcription api and for some reason every time I use parseInt(speech) it returns NaN despite there being a number in the text

Here is my code:

```
${parseInt(req.body.Speech)}
```

Here are the logs:

```
SPEECH:
your code is 156 please enter the code now,

CODE:
NaN
```

I am not sure at all why it is doing this. To my knowledge it should just be returning the 156. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the whole string? This won't work

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, if `parseInt` encounters something that's not a number, it will stop there and until that, whatever number it encountered, it will try to parse. Your string starts with only string.

```
your code is 156 please enter the code now,
```

The moment it sees `y` on the first character, it stops, as `y` is not a part of any of the number systems (hexadecimal has `a` through `f`). So until this, it has parsed an empty string `""`. So, `parseInt("")` is technically `NaN` or Not a Number.

So you can do anything like that has a number inside a string along with a string:

```js
// Possible
console.log(parseInt("15 kg"));        //  15
console.log(parseInt("120 seconds"));  // 120

// Not Possible
console.log(parseInt("Hello 420"));    // NaN
```

If you still need to find numbers from your string, what you can do is to use `RegEx`:

```js
// Possible
console.log(parseInt("15 kg"));        //  15
console.log(parseInt("120 seconds"));  // 120

// Possible with Regex
console.log(parseInt("Hello 420 Folks".replace(/^\D+|\D+$/g, "")));                              // 420
console.log(parseInt("your code is 156 please enter the code now,".replace(/^\D+|\D+$/g, "")));  // 156
```

---

From the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified `radix`, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt works only on the string containing the numbers. If your string contains alpha numeric values. it does not work. you must be extract your number from the string and then convert into number or parse int.
another thing you can try with Number("pass your string here").

I recommend, from your backend just send the code in your reponse.body.speech. on the frontend you can make this whole string like
"your code is {{request.body.speech}} please enter the code now"

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the Number, try something like that:

```js
let fullSentence = "your code is 156 please enter the code now,";

fullSentence = fullSentence.match(/\d/g).join("")

console.log(parseInt(fullSentence));
```

It checks if your sentence has numbers, and the put all them together, and finally parses the string to int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex...

```js
const getNum = s => parseInt(s.replace(/^\D+/g,''))

console.log( getNum('your code is 156 please enter the code now') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first extract the number from the sentence, and then convert it to integer.

```js
const sentence = "your code is 156 please enter the code now,";

const res = sentence.match(/\d+/g);

if (res){
   console.log(parseInt(res[0], 10));
} else {
   console.log("there was no number on the input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several numbers in your string and you want an array with every number, you can use the `split` function with a regex:

```
'abc123def456'.split(/\D/).filter(Boolean) // [123, 456]
```

`.split(/\D/)` will split on not numerical characters, removing them

`.filter(Boolean)` will remove empty string items in the array